# Dell XPS USB-C to DVI-D not working

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, dvi, thunderbolt

I've got an Dell XPS 15 9560, and I've bought a USB-C to DVI adapter:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/ICZI-USB-C-Thunderbolt-Compatible-Adapter/dp/B01MU2WQWD/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1492521757&sr=1-1&keywords=usb-c+to+dvi

Windows recognises the monitor, shows it up in display settings but I get no picture. I can drag windows off the edge of my 2nd screen (via HDMI-DVI) onto the 3rd screen (USB-C to DVI) but the screen stays black.

I've got latest Nvidia drivers (the ones that it shipped with were out of date) I've tried both a Benq and LG monitor, neither work on the USB port but both work on the HDMI port, so they are fine.

I've got a replacement adapter sent out and it still doesn't work.

Is USB-C to DVI-D just not possible?

Should I try USB-C to VGA or HDMI

Why would windows detect the monitor in settings but not render it?

Am I just dealing with dodgy display adapters?

Should I be saying USB-C or Thunderbolt?

Here's an image from the Nvidia control panel, showing the hardware is properly detected

[image]

**UPDATE**

Got a response from the vendor that sold me the laptop, this was what they said:

```
The thunderbolt connection is not compatible with a DVi connection.  
You will require a USB-C to display port adapter and a display port 
male to display port male cable.
```

So according to them thunderbolt/usb-c is not compatible with DVI.

Comment: It’s unclear how this adapter is supposed to work or what connection type it even uses. Is it Thunderbolt (PCIe)? Or Thunderbolt (DisplayPort)? Or USB? Or DisplayPort? I’m relatively sure this isn’t a scam, but the details are *very* scarce.

Comment: So do you reckon the adapter's the problem (whether it's a scam, broken, incompatible or whatever) - what sort of adapter do I need?

Comment: I want to ask, you didn't use USB-C to DVI (then DVI-VGA adapter) right ? another point to think of is the following : if it's detected under windows, it should be working. Did you verify that it's using a proper refresh rate/resolution combo ?

Comment: I've got the above linked adapter plugged into the USB-C, then a DVI-D to DVI-D (male on both ends) cable. The monitor is set to 1920x1080 - native 22 inch 1080 resolution, resolution recommended by windows

Comment: I did wonder if it would some how be the refresh rate, but no idea how to change that in windows and can't get any built in menu up on the monitor

Comment: I tried a non-native res as well, 1680x1050, that didn't do anything

Comment: I'm going to buy a different adapter and see if that works - although USB-C to HDMI seems to be a more popular choice

Comment: You're referring to this dongle's display as your "third screen"... Have you tried with only two total, rather than three?

Comment: Yup - laptop screen and HDMI/DVI both work, laptop screen and USB-C/DVI only the laptop screen works. In fact since I've unplugged the USB-C and rebooted windows has stopped recognizing it

Comment: This is the PhysX configuration you've shown us. PhysX DOES deal with video cards, but it isn't about putting images on screens. What does Display Settings show?

Comment: @music2myear the windows display settings didn't show the names of the monitors, that's why I used the physx screen. Right now windows is only showing my 2 screens - since I disconnected and reconnected the USB-C it's not showing the screen at all

Comment: I'd love to tag this question with USB-C, I feel it's worth while as USB-C is a massively different beast with all the extra adapters and potential uses for it. I don't have privileges to add the tag though, would appreciate someone else doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter was incompatible.

I spoke to the manufacturer who confirmed it would work on a 13" model, but not a 15" model.

Possibly a problem with the dedicated card that comes with the 15 but not the 13 inch XPS.

I bought a DELL DA200 which work perfectly straight away, plug and play:
http://accessories.ap.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=sg&l=en&s=bsd&cs=sgbsd1&sku=470-abnl

Note this adapter is a VGA or HDMI display port (only one monitor at a time on it), plus an ethernet and usb port.
So I can't confirm if it's switching from DVI to VGA (What I'm now using) - this is an entirely different and more expensive piece of kit, but it still carries a display signal through the USB-C port.

I spoke to dell about the matter as well, they said I would need the DA200 NOT the DA100, a slightly older version of the hub which is also not compatible with the latest XPS15 (but it looks identical to me, so be wary if of getting the right one if you have the same problem)

So to summarize, the Dell branded DA200 works great as a USB-C to HDMI or VGA adapter

According to Dell the DA100 WILL NOT WORK and the ICZI USB-C to DVI is also NOT compatible.

I wish I could give more technical reasons, but USB-C seems to more complicated than just buying an adapter and plugging it in.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Windows11 (22H2) and Linux (Fedora36) on a [ThinkPad Lenovo P15](https://geizhals.eu/lenovo-thinkpad-p15-g1-20st000dge-a2381376.html) via Thunderbold3 aswell via USB3-with-DP. Those plugs work with a 3840x2160-USB-C-Monitor, but not with my cheap AliExpress-USBC-to-DVI-cable.

I found three people ([Ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2393560), [ThinkPenguin](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/laptops-enabling-displayport-over-usb-cthunderbolt), [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043761/connecting-second-montor-trough-usb-c-to-dvi-adapter/1046471#1046471))  who said that they had to switch in Bios: `Display Digital Interface` from `DDI to mPD` (miniDisplayport) to `DDI to TBT`(Thunderbolt) and that solved the issue, however I do not have this option since I do not have a mDP.

Screen (Manufacturer, Model, Resolution) is recognised and used/extended by Windows, but screen keeps blank, as reported by the questioner.
On my Windows I see `BillBoard Device` in my Device-Mangager and in my USB-Unplug-Icon, if I plug in the cable (even without Monitor).
[Someone at reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/k9fnq3/dvi_monitor_recognized_as_billboard_device/) had the same issue, which might be related to a cheap USB2-cable not supporting USB3.x .

[image]